# Why does the c'tor of std::runtime_error take a constant reference to std::string?

Tags: c++, exception, memory-management, reference

According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error), one of the c'tors of `std::runtime_error` has the following signature:

```
explicit runtime_error( const std::string& what_arg );
```

However (I assume) the freshly constructed exception object is required to hold a copy of that `std::string` argument anyways. So why is the argument given by const ref (rather than by value)?

Is my assumption wrong?

Comment: So you could pass temporary objects? Or string literals (before C++11)?

Comment: You're trying to argue that the copy should be made at the call site, and then the constructor should just move it from the argument to the member variable? If so: what's the difference? Passing "large" input arguments by const reference is a C++ idiom. It's the default unless you have a very good reason to do otherwise. Move semantics notwithstanding.

Comment: @KubaOber "Passing "large" input arguments by const reference is a C++ idiom." this is C++98 idiom, with move semantics it is questionable.

Comment: @Slave ...assumption being that rvalue reference is what we want. And we don't always want it - recall that it modifies the source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass by value wouldn't be useful anyway. You might be thinking about passing a `std::string&&`, though. According to the [cppreference.com page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error) you posted.

> Because copying std::exception is not permitted to throw exceptions, this message is typically stored internally as a separately-allocated reference-counted string. This is also why there is no constructor taking std::string&&: it would have to copy the content anyway.

`std::runtime_error` is not supposed to hold a `std::string` because if it did, copying the exception could result in another exception due to failure to allocate space for a copy. One way to sidestep this is to use a reference counted buffer and copy the argument to that buffer. Given that a copy has to be made, an `std::string&&` overload provides no benefit.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I was not able to see the implication of copying not being permitted to throw until you pointed it out. But it makes perfect sense that this prevents the object from holding a copy. And as soon as no copy is held, I of course do agree with passing by const ref.

Answer (score 2):

You should always take the string as a const reference. It avoids making **two** copies of it.

If you accepted it as a string, it would have to first construct it. Then when putting it into a class member, it would have to copy construct it.

This may not be so inefficient with move operations but some of us still have to write C++ code for Visual Studio 2008, or Redhat Linux 5, and can't use C++11, 14 or 17.

And besides that, when std::exception was created there weren't any move operations in the C++ standard.

Comment: "You should always take the string as a const reference." this is not right statement since move semantics were added. At least it is questionable, but passing by value can be even more efficient than const reference.

Comment: *"Then when putting it into a class member, it would have to copy construct it."* Unless you move it.

Comment: Guys, guys, I covered moving and why it can't always be used right there in the second paragraph.